# Is there a way to add variables into an array, like some sorts of an inventory?

Tags: python

I'm making a text based game, based on the 1800s and survival, I'm trying to make an inventory system where, if you buy certain things from a shop, it adds it into an array, which is your inventory of course.

```
inv = ["empty"]

shop_name = "Liams Necessities"
mattress = 40 #the numbers are the price assigned
water = 5
revolver = 60
#etc
```

I have the buying it system sorted out, but i want to know how to update the array if you buy multiple items from different shops.

Comment: You can append to lists by using `.append()` method on the list. Please do not confuse lists and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly by default python does not use array it's use the list. To use array you need to use numpy in python .

So in your question I have seen that you are using list so you can use `.append()` to insert a value in the list.

```
inv = ["empty"]
inv.append("xyz")
print(inv)
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for a [Counter object](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html). But of course you can also use a list. This is how you would append using a list:

```
>>> inv = ["empty"]
>>> inv.append("a")
>>> inv.append("b")
>>> print(inv)
['empty', 'a', 'b']
```

But as the inventory gets large and you have to manage things like duplicates and counting objects, the Counter object becomes more appealing:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> cnt['a'] += 1
>>> cnt['b'] += 1
>>> cnt['a'] += 10
>>> print(cnt)
Counter({'a': 11, 'b': 1})
```